# Can't Overwrite Text File - PHP

Tags: php

I have this PHP code on my website, but the isn't working.
What it does, is every time someone clicks the button, the counter goes up one.
I can get the content of the file, and increase it by one, but it can't overwrite the old number, so the count stays at one.

Could  I have some help?

Code:

```
<?php
$fn = "count.txt";
$orig = file_get_contents($fn);
$plus1 = $orig + 1;

file_put_contents($fn, $plus1);

echo $plus1;
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What OS / web server are you running?

Comment: Check the folder permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a problem with file permissions. You need to make sure that the user your web server is running as has permissions to write to the file. In Ubuntu/Apache, the web server generally runs as www-data. In that case changing the owner of the file to www-data would allow the server to write to the file.

```
chown www-data count.txt
```